# HDMI not listed by xrandr (hybrid graphics card)

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, xrandr

After a reboot my external monitor suddenly stopped working. I am not sure how to debug this. My monitor cannot be found in the display configuration. xrandr does not list a HDMI (it does list a VGA1, my laptop has both an HDMI and VGA adapter, is that related?).

I have had many troubles with my hybrid nvidia/intel gpu since the day i got this laptop (not this issue though). I have tried a whole bunch of stuff (switching to proprietary driver, try different version, back to xorg nouveau driver, install bumblebee again...), but nothing has worked with respect to this issue. I have now put nouveau.modset=0 in my grub config and I have removed all nvidia/bumblebee stuff (`sudo apt-get purge nvidia* '^bumblebee.*'`), I am more than happy to never use my nvidia card again (I only got it because I was hoping it would improve my Blender experience). Can I keep this setup?

But regardless, this did not make the HDMI monitor work. Is it possible the HDMI connector itself is broken? (there were no issues before at all). The monitor works fine with another laptop.
What should I do to investigate this issue further? I obviously would love to keep using my HDMI port ;-).

dmesg: https://pastebin.com/zbSDxyZA

journalctl -b: https://pastebin.com/vGbNenMM

xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

sudo lshw -C video

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

**UPDATE**

I got a suspicion my issue was somehow caused by a kernel update. (earlier issues pointed in this direction as well). After executing `sudo apt install linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic` my HDMI port is working again. I am not sure what happened (I don't even really know what that command has installed, I guess maybe the boot image was updated). But uname -r is still `4.4.0-101-generic`. I would be very glad if someone can explain me what is going on here, and if a bug report should be submitted.

**UPDATE 2**

I was silly and did not install the headers first (I don't actually know what I'm doing, I am just frantically trying to get my hdmi working again). So after looking at the apt logs this is what happened:

```
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic.
(Reading database ... 481714 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic_4.4.0-91.114_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.4.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-91-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic (4.4.0-91.114) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic (4.4.0-91.114) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(4.4.0-91.114 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(4.4.0-91.114 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-91-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-91-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-91-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-91-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-91-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-91-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-91-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-91-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-91-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-91-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-91-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-91-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-91-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-91-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-91-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-101-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-91-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

It seems that somewhere here something happened that made my hdmi port work again.

Comment: Data point: I'm using 4.4.0-101-generic and my HDMI port works fine (old AMD card).

Comment: Maybe something else executed by apk when trying to (and failing) to revert to an older kernel resolved my issue. maybe depmod. But I can only guess now what caused this issue in the first place.